# Java Insert subquery sql statement for mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

may i know whats wrong with my insert sql statement at java as the sql statement allows me to insert everything into database, leaving my profilepic empty. Currently, what im trying to do is that, i am trying to duplicate the image from userId=143 into the new user. However, the duplication of image doesn't work at java.

On the other hand, at mysql database registration table, there is data for userId=143 and with image. I tried to execute the following sql statement and it works prefectly as what i wanted.

```
    insert into registration 
(profilepic, firstName,lastName,phoneNo,dateOfBirth,displayname,password,
emailAddress, address, interest ) 
select (select profilepic from registration where userId = 
143),'ab','cd',94329,'2016-11-11','af','de','gf','ge','ee' ;
```

However, it doesn't work if i use the exact format for sql statement at java. I'm not able to figure out what's wrong with my sql statement. Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
 try{
                                    DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
                                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);
                                    // connects to the database
                                    conn = getConnection();

                                    // constructs SQL statement
                                  stmt = conn.createStatement();


                                    String sql1 =" insert into registration (profilepic, firstName, lastName,phoneNo,dateOfBirth,displayname,password,emailAddress, address, interest ) select (select profilepic from registration where userId = 143),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? ";
                                    //Using a PreparedStatement to save the file
                                    PreparedStatement statement1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
                                    statement1.setString(1, firstName);
                                    statement1.setString(2, lastName);
                                    statement1.setString(3, phoneNo);
                                    statement1.setString(4, dateOfBirth); 
                                  statement1.setString(5, displayName);
                                    statement1.setString(6, password);

                                    statement1.setString(7,emailAddress);
                                    statement1.setString(8, address);


                                    statement1.setString(9, interest);



                                    //sends the statement to the database server
                                    int row = statement1.executeUpdate();
                                    if (row > 0) {
                                      getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Message.jsp").include(request, response);
                                      //  message = "You have successfully registered.";
                                    }


                                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                                //  message = "You have failed to registered. Please try again.";
                                 //   ex.printStackTrace();
                                } finally {
                                    if (conn != null) {
                                        // closes the database connection
                                        try {
                                            conn.close();
                                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                                            // ex.printStackTrace();
                                            //silent
                                            //message="You have failed to log in";
                                             getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/FailedMsg.jsp").include(request, response);
                                        }
                                    }




                          }
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @Andreas what i meant is that i could not duplicate the image using sql statement at java. When i execute the code at java using the sql statement for profile picture, it gives me empty image. 
However, i think the sql statement should work as i tried the same sql statement at mysql. It achieves what i wanted to get. But, i am not able to find out what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your query like below having only a single `SELECT` statement and avoiding the inner sub-select.

```
insert into registration 
(profilepic, firstName,lastName,phoneNo,dateOfBirth,displayname,password,
emailAddress, address, interest ) 
select profilepic,'ab','cd',94329,
'2016-11-11','af','de','gf','ge','ee'
from registration 
where userId = 143;
```